# Are screenshots of malware eligible for copyright protection?

Tags: copyright

There was a case in which a screenshot of a piece of ransomware (a dialog box asking for ransom) was uploaded to Wikimedia Commons. It is was claimed that this screenshot is rendered ineligible for copyright protection by the legal doctrine of *ex turpi causa non oritur actio* (Latin for "from a dishonorable cause an action does not arise").

My questions are:

- Is this correct in the United States of America?
- Is this correct in the United Kingdom?

By "is this correct" I mean whether the doctrine is valid in the queried countries and isf so, whether it applies to copyright.

Comment: I doubt that a simple screenshot is capable of copyright protection as it is not a piece of work.

Comment: Relevant: "[Copyrighted Crimes: The Copyrightability of Illegal Works](http://digitalcommons.law.yale.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1108&context=yjolt)" by Eldar Haber, 2014

Comment: A screenshot would be a copy, display or distribution of the underlying copyrighted work published by the author.  The author of a web page may obtain a registered copyright and sue for infringement (in US courts). Whether a federal court would grant relief is a different question. A site publishing an unauthorized copy may certainly be served with a DMCA takedown notice.